# Is there any way to disable oracle Multitenant feature

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, pluggable-database

We are using Oracle docker image for Oracle database 12.2.

By default it seems the Multitenant feature is enabled.

Is there any way it can be disabled?

We have only one application to support and do not want to create pluggable database for that.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @APC for your comments, If you see AWS RDS(oracle) - they mentioned in documentation that it is not supported in their environment. So I guess there must be some configuration which they would have disabled to achieve this. ref : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html#Oracle.Concepts.FeatureSupport.12c     search for keyword : Multitenant

Comment: Looks like non multitenant will be desupported in 20 so AWS RDS will have to adapt or clarify what they mean https://mikedietrichde.com/2019/09/17/3-pdbs-included-with-oracle-19c-and-desupport-of-non-cdbs-with-20c/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fair warning:

The non-CDB architecture is [desupported starting in Oracle Database 20c](https://mikedietrichde.com/2019/09/17/3-pdbs-included-with-oracle-19c-and-desupport-of-non-cdbs-with-20c/).

You can use the CDB architecture with one user-created PDB without a Multitenant license. From Oracle Database 19c, this [extended to three user-created PDBs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87) in a CDB.

The short answer is there's no way to disable the CDB architecture.

To switch to it, you'll need to install a new non-CDB database. Then migrate the data from your existing database to it. For example with Data Pump export/import or some other data replication/migration tool.

Comment: Thanks Chris. For my use case I wanted to create a non-CDB database by modifying dbca.rsp.tmpl and dockerfile, but I see these are not going to survive since as you mentioned this architecture is not recommended and desupported altogether from 20c onwards. Thanks for suggestion and guidance. :)